# Oracle SQL iterate loop user_tables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

There are 3 tables (TB1, TB2, TB3)

```
sql> SELECT table_name FROM user_tables
TB1
TB2
TB3
```

All tables have same columns like

(name email phone)

I hope to get ALL `email` values by loop into `user_tables`,

The expected result is union all tables' `email` like as below

xxx@gmail.com // from TB1
yyy@gmail.com // from TB1
zzz@gmail.com // from TB2
abc@gmail.com // from TB3
...

This is sql script I tried but failed:

```
BEGIN
    FOR get_table_list IN ( SELECT table_name FROM user_tables)
    LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT email from ' || get_table_list;
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UNION ALL';
    END LOOP;
END;
```

ERROR MESSGE:

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 4, column 27:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to '||'
ORA-06550: line 4, column 9:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Comment: `execute immediate` should receive a syntactically correct statement that should be possible to execute as a standalone statement. Obviously, `union all` is invalid and you either need to build the overall statement for all involved tables or execute statement per table with `bulk collect`. But it would be better to describe your final task, as the approach seems to be quite strange

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that all your tables have an `email` column then loop through the tables and build the SQL and then call `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` once:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_sql    CLOB := NULL;
  v_emails SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST;
BEGIN
  FOR r IN (SELECT table_name FROM user_tables)
  LOOP
    IF v_sql IS NULL THEN
      v_sql := 'SELECT email from ' || r.table_name;
    ELSE
      v_sql := v_sql || ' UNION ALL SELECT email from ' || r.table_name;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql BULK COLLECT INTO v_emails;

  -- Do something with the emails.
  FOR i IN 1 .. v_emails.COUNT
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_emails(i));
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 (email) AS
SELECT 'alice@example.com' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'betty@example.com' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'carol@example.com' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'debra@example.com' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table2 (email) AS
SELECT 'emily@example.com' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'fiona@example.com' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table3 (email) AS
SELECT 'gerri@example.com' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> emily@example.com
> fiona@example.com
> alice@example.com
> betty@example.com
> carol@example.com
> debra@example.com
> gerri@example.com
> ```

Or, without the collection:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_sql CLOB := NULL;
  v_cur SYS_REFCURSOR; 
  v_email  VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  FOR r IN (SELECT table_name FROM user_tables)
  LOOP
    IF v_sql IS NULL THEN
      v_sql := 'SELECT email from ' || r.table_name;
    ELSE
      v_sql := v_sql || ' UNION ALL SELECT email from ' || r.table_name;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;

  OPEN v_cur FOR v_sql;
  LOOP
    FETCH v_cur INTO v_email;
    EXIT WHEN v_cur%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_email);
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE v_cur;
END;
/
```

or

```sql
DECLARE
  v_cur    SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_email  VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  FOR r IN (SELECT table_name FROM user_tables)
  LOOP
    OPEN v_cur FOR 'SELECT email from ' || r.table_name;
    LOOP
      FETCH v_cur INTO v_email;
      EXIT WHEN v_cur%NOTFOUND;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_email);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE v_cur;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Which output the same.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/IfpwmtVn)

Comment: Only that kind of bulk collect on lots of data may lead to an out of memory error.

Comment: @BogdanDincescu Added another option without using a collection.

Answer (score 1):

Why not a simple union?

```
create or replace view v_email as
select email from tb1
union all
select email from tb2
union all
select email from tb3;
```

Why do you think you need PL/SQL for that?

Comment: I want to get tables by iterate user_tables, because I will create more tables so I hope there is a general solution.

Comment: I see. How about creating a **view**, then? When you create another table, recreate the view - that takes no time and works well. Besides, as it seems you're storing email addresses throughout *many* tables, just asking - did you normalize your data model?

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I'll survey how to use **view**. I'm beginner of SQL haha. The email is just an example, I only want to get the value of specific column from all tables.

Comment: I edited code I posted to show how to - in a simple manner - create a view. So, once you create another table, you'd just put `union all select email from tab4` to the end of this script, run it and everyone who uses that view instantly sees new emails by `select * from v_email`. To me, it looks like a simple solution.